# как выйти из PyGlet после воспроизведения аудио?

Tags: python-3.x, аудио

```
import pyglet
def audio(files):
    media = pyglet.media.load(files)
    media.play()
    pyglet.app.run()

audio("C:\\audio.mp3")
```

Имеется следующий код, как сделать так что бы после воспроизведения аудио дорожки, программа продолжила свою работу, а не осталась висеть в PyGlet, другими словами, как выйти из PyGlet после воспроизведения аудио?

Answer (score 0):

*Как вариант запустить функцию в потоке*

```
import pyglet
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep


def audio(files):
    media = pyglet.media.load(files)
    media.play()
    pyglet.app.run()

def main():
    player = Thread(target=audio, args=("Audio/Eminem Crazy In Love.mp3",))
    player.start()
    name = input("Введите ваше имя")
    print(name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```